# Searching for the best one word term for having to log in again

Tags: terminology

There is a web application. You log in to the app and work with it.

Then you take a break.

When you come back after 30 minutes you want to continue, but you can't. There is a popup window which says:

"We have a security measure. When you are logged in to the session and the account is idle for longer than 15 minutes, you have to log in again."

What is the best title for this popup window.
Is re-authentication the best term for this? Or is another term better suited for this?

Thanks alot in advance

Comment: If you wanted to use "re-authentication" you could say something like "Please re-authenticate to return to your account".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reauthenticate is probably the most ideal word to use, yes.

If that is an exact quote, however, you may want to consider writing it as:

"Your account has been idle for longer than fifteen minutes.  Please reauthenticate for your security."

Comment: also, reauthenticate does not actually require a hyphen.

Answer (score 2):

You could use several synonyms for the exact word you are looking for:

> Re-verify (you are who you say you are)
>
> Reauthenticate (your access)
>
> Revalidate (your credentials)

However, I would suggest that your login window can simply have the title

> Please log in again